"Electric Field at the Center of a solid Hemisphere: Where Did I Go Wrong?
I am currrently studying electrostatics and got stuck in a problem. I am trying to calculate the electric field at the center of a solid hemisphere with uniform charge density. Here is my approach:

Problem Setup:

I have a solid hemisphere with radius $R$ and uniform charge density $\rho$.

I am trying to calculate the electric field at the center of the flat circular face of the hemisphere.


Taking center as the origin,I considered a small volume element $dV$ as a circular disc of thickness $ dy $ defined as $dV = \pi r^2 \theta \, dr \,$




The charge element is given by
$$
dq = \pi r^2 \, dy \cdot \rho \  \\ \sigma = \frac{\text{Charge}}{\text{Surface area}} = \rho \, dy 
$$
Since $y = R \cos \theta$, we have
$$
dy = -R \sin \theta \, d\theta 
$$
The differential electric field is
$$
dE = \frac{\sigma}{2 \varepsilon_0}(1-\cos \theta) = \frac{\rho \, dy}{2 \varepsilon_0}(1-\cos \theta) 
$$
Thus, the net electric field is
$$
\begin{aligned}
E_{\text{net}} & = \int dE = \int_0^{\pi / 2} \frac{\rho (-R \sin \theta \, d\theta)}{2 \varepsilon_0}(1-\cos \theta) \\
& = \frac{\rho R}{2 \varepsilon_0} \int_0^{\pi / 2} \left( \cos \theta - 1 \right) \sin \theta \, d\theta \\
& = \frac{\rho R}{2 \varepsilon_0} \int_0^{\pi / 2} \left( \frac{\sin 2\theta}{2} - \sin \theta \right) \, d\theta \\
& = \frac{\rho R}{2 \varepsilon_0} \left[ \cos \theta - \frac{\cos 2\theta}{4} \right]_0^{\pi / 2} \\
& = -\frac{\rho R}{4 \varepsilon_0}
\end{aligned}
$$
Problem:
However when I tried solving this with another method I got the same result but positive which is the true result the same as given in books. Where might I be going wrong in my calculation? Is there an issue with my setup, integration limits, or assumptions?
